# ata1:comreset failed (errno=-32) error while booting brand new computer

Tags: boot, sata, ata

I try to install fedora to a new desktop computer I have but I am getting `ata1:comreset failed (errno=-32)` error while starting fedora installation. After a long while it stars with the installation interface but errors with that specific one all around. Do you know any thing about that error.

Answer (score 2):

Problem was about connection problem to my SATA1. I check it out and everything has gone to normal.

Comment: Do you mean there was a problem with the physical connection with the SATA drive?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the partition you want to install the O.S is primary and is in active disk drive,then retry install the O.S.
You can change you partitions by partedmagic or any other software,Acronis,paragon,Easus or any other one.